# На кампусе или в кампусе?

Tags: предлог

Не могу найти правильного употребления - на кампусе или в кампусе? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта.

On campus, перевод:

1) на кампусе, на территории кампуса, на территории университета, на территории комплекса, на Campus.

Предлог "НА"  обычно используется в том случае, если речь идет о территории, например: Университету 100 лет, это очень много для Канады. Это самое старое здание на кампусе, тех лет постройки.  Школа расположена на кампусе Доклэндс Университета Восточного Лондона.

Также: "Когда я приехала на Кампус, то оказалось, что я окружена интересными, целеустремленными и креативными людьми".

2) в кампусе, в студенческом городке, в университетском городке.

Студенческая жизнь в кампусе. В парижском кампусе действует более 50 студенческих клубов и ассоциаций.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что все-таки "в кампусе". Кампус - университетский городок, так? Где? - в городке. Где? - в кампусе.

Answer (score 0):

Если не перепутали с камбузом, то все правильно)